# Help - chromium display frozen but the app keeps working

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, manjaro, i3

I am new to Manjaro and Arch. Recently I started running into an issue that I don't know how to solve.

**The Issue**

The chromium and skypeforlinux windows freeze, but the apps keep running.
For example skype calls don't break off but the window is stuck.
Same with chrome and chromium. If I am chatting (say telegram web) and the issue happens I can still send messages, but the screen does not update. So I am acting 'blindly'.
Other Apps like Emacs (also installed with yay), Telegram (yay) or terminal (native urxvt) are uneffected.

Another symptom: When I have Emacs running on Screen 1 and a broken Chrome on Screen 2, and when I switch from 1 to 2, then the window continues to show the contents of Screen 1, in this case emacs.

What is happening?

**My system:**

Manjaro Architect (uname -a): Linux archangel 5.1.4-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 22 17:56:21 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux

pacman --version: Pacman v5.1.3 - libalpm v11.0.3

i3 --version: i3 version 4.16.1 (2019-01-27)

yay --version: yay v9.2.0 - libalpm v11.0.3

**Effected apps (installed with yay/pacman):**

skypeforlinux: skypeforlinux-preview-bin 8.47.76.58-1

chromium --version: Chromium 75.0.3770.80 Manjaro Linux

Comment: edit: shortended the question and fixed typo

Comment: the issue arose for the first time after running a recent systemupgrade (pacman -Syyuu)

Comment: when running chromium with from cli I get many `[31987:31987:0614/074925.816172:ERROR:zygote_communication_linux.cc(276)] Failed to send GetTerminationStatus message to zygote` errors when the issue occurs

Comment: Just use web.skype.com if you must use Skype, no binaries needed.

Comment: chromium is the bigger problem.

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the same issue on NixOS with all chrome apps (Chromium, Spotify, ...)  I am already using DRI2 @FinnFrotscher

Answer (score 5):

I recently had the same issue.
In my case, the problem was solved by forcing DRI 2 instead of DRI 3
(I have an intel graphic card with the intel drivers).

I basically followed the instructions given here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics#DRI3_issues

In a nutshell, I had to write

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "DRI" "2"
EndSection
```

in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Seems to have worked for me. I was unable to use linux kernel >= 4.20 for a significant period of time without losing windows, but after applying this config the behavior has not repeated.

Comment: Can somebody tell me how to adapt this to also work with the proprietary NVidia drivers? My vscode freezes for 1-2 seconds the again and again. The only solution I found is to start code with --disable-gpu.

Comment: Using DRI 2 breaks Vulkan support for me